# tabbar with theme

Tags: faces, themes, tabbar

I want to remove a white border of the tabbar.

[image]

(The strange color choice is only for checking the configuration of faces.)

As you can see, the right part of tabbar has a white border and I can not change its color from the tabbar's `set-face-attribute`.

After some tries I have found that the reason of the border comes from [`afternoon`](https://emacsthemes.com/themes/afternoon-theme.html) theme. But I can not figure out which setting I should modify el-file.

How can I remove the border or change its color?

```
(load-theme 'afternoon t)

(require 'tabbar)

(setq tabbar-buffer-groups-function nil)
(dolist (btn '(tabbar-buffer-home-button
               tabbar-scroll-left-button
               tabbar-scroll-right-button))
  (set btn (cons (cons "" nil)
             (cons "" nil))))
(setq tabbar-separator '(1.5))

;; face settings (has no effects on the border...)
(set-face-attribute
 'tabbar-default nil
 :family "Noto Sans"
 :background "darkgreen"
 :foreground "gray80"
 :box nil
 :height 1.0)
(set-face-attribute
 'tabbar-unselected nil
 :background "darkred"
 :foreground "gray80"
 :box nil)
(set-face-attribute
 'tabbar-selected nil
 :background "darkblue"
 :foreground "SkyBlue1"
 :box nil)
(set-face-attribute
 'tabbar-button nil
 :box nil)
(set-face-attribute
 'tabbar-separator nil
 :height 1.2)

(tabbar-mode 1)
```

**EDIT**. If I comment out the line for `afternoon`, the white border disappeared.

[image]

- openSUSE Leap 15.0
- Version 25.3.1 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30)

Comment: My notes indicate that `tabbar-default` is indeed the llikely suspect, so you might want to type `M-x customize-face` ... and see if your theme is modifying your preferred settings.  The only other thing I can think of is to make sure that `tabbar-background-color` is `nil`.

Comment: I also thought so. But any setting for tabbar-default does not seem to work for the border. I can change only the background color.

Comment: There are only three likely `:box` suspects in the theme that I can see:  **(1)** https://github.com/osener/emacs-afternoon-theme/blob/master/afternoon-theme.el#L301 ; **(2)** https://github.com/osener/emacs-afternoon-theme/blob/master/afternoon-theme.el#L168 ; and, **(3)** https://github.com/osener/emacs-afternoon-theme/blob/master/afternoon-theme.el#L172 .  However, I didn't find those inside my version of `tabbar.el`.  Perhaps your particular build of Emacs uses `widget-field`, or something you are using is inheriting `mode-line` or `mode-line-inactive` ....

Comment: Thanks! The second one is bingo. Namely the tabbar uses the face of (active) mode line. If I remove `:color ,foreground`, the white border is "removed" and the border-color around the file name in the mode line becomes purple.